# Can I be notified about DDL command execution from MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, ddl

ALL,

It is not possible inside mySQL, but maybe it can be done inside MariaDB?

TIA!

[EDIT]

ON MS SQL Server it can be achieved by using `CREATE QUEUE + CREATE SERVICE + CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION` and then query the notification queue.

It is also possible to use `LISTEN/NOTIFY` in recent PostgreSQL to do the same.

It looks like mySQL/MariaDB do not support this feature and the only way to check is to query the information_schema.tables and compare the number of tables you get with the number of tables you have initially.

[/EDIT]

Comment: What do you mean by be notified? Like you want to receive a desktop notification, or an email, or a notification to your phone? Or in the terminal? Is it a command you are executing or one that is set to execute on a schedule? Or all DDL commands in general? Are you wanting to be notified for security reasons if someone other than you is issuing a command?

Comment: @DustinNieffenegger, I'm writing a software in C++, which will want to know about CREATE/ALTER/DROP TABLE/INDEX execution in order to update its table list. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB has the same security constraints.

You can always get the list of tables by `SELECT ... FROM information_schema.tables ...`

Another way to check:

```
mysqldump --no-data --routines
```

then diff the output from the previous dump of the schema.

However, I would not want to do this too often, no more than once a minute, for fear that it would interfere with other things too much.

Comment: so there is no special notification to the client? I know I can run this `SELECT...`, but what about `ALTER TABLE`? This will keep the DB busy a lot, which I try to avoid.

Comment: @Igor - DDL commands should be very rare.  What are you trying to find?  Hackers?  Naughty programmers?  Auditing of what is going on?  Something else?  Check out MariaDB's auditing capabilities.  How fast to you need to spot a change -- within a minute?  within a day?

Comment: @Igor - Also review the `GRANTs` -- avoid root except from localhost; don't let everyone have SUPER; apps should be limited to the database then need to touch; etc.

Comment: please see my edit of the OP. Am I right in my presumption?

Comment: @Igor - Those features you mention in other products are not available in MySQL or MariaDB.  I added another approach to my Answer.

Comment: OK, so I was right and this is not available in mySQL/MariaDB. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @Igor - See if anything in [_this_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-audit-plugin/) might help.